# sparkSQL wrong result

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

My spark version is 1.5.0,and i use spark-SQL in spark-shell do some ETL,here is my code:

```
import com.databricks.spark.avro._
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
import java.security.MessageDigest

val dfGoods = sqlContext.read.avro("hdfs:///user/data/date=*")
dfGoods.registerTempTable("goodsinfo")

val dfGoodsLmt=sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM (SELECT goodsid, etype, goodsattribute, row_number() over (partition by goodsid order by runid DESC) rank_num FROM goodsinfo) tmp WHERE rank_num =1")
```

i use `dfGoodsLmt.count()` to see the row number,first time the result is always wrong,but after that, i rerun the code `dfGoodsLmt.count()` ,the result is right.I have tried many times,I don't know why.

here is a demo code and the result should be 1000,but i need to try more than once to get the right answer.
`case class data(id:Int,name:Int)
val tmp=(1 to 1000) zip (1 to 1000)
tmp.map(x=>data(x._1,x._2)).toDF.registerTempTable("test_table")
sqlContext.sql("select * from (select *,row_number() over(partition by id order by id DESC)rank from test_table)tmp where rank=1").count`

Comment: Unless you can provide [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is extremely unlikely we'll be able to help you.

Comment: @zero323 `case class data(id:Int,name:Int) val tmp=(1 to 1000) zip (1 to 1000) tmp.map(x=>data(x._1,x._2)).toDF.registerTempTable("test_table") sqlContext.sql("select * from (select *,row_number() over(partition by id order by id DESC)rank from test_table)tmp where rank=1").count`

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem. Is this behavior specific to any cluster particular cluster manger?

Comment: @zero323
I use CDH5.5.0